# Cannot install intelhaxm.exe

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. 
i tried to run install intelhaxm.exe but could not do it,because of the error as follows:
 This computer does not support Intel Visualization Technology(VT-x).Haxm cannot be installed.Please refer to intel HAXM documentation for more details.

i tried looking if my hardware supports visualization technology and came to know that my hardware cannot support visualization technology...
 Is there any way to make the system support?
 I really need this so that i can start my android Programming.

Comment: Intel Virtualisation Technology is a processor facility. Your computer either has it or it doesn't. It's possible that it can be enabled by a BIOS setting, but if not there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no `Intel Visualization Technology`. It is called [Intel Virtualisation Technology](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology).

Search your CPU model on [Intel](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology) to see if it has this feature. If it has it, then it is disabled. Look in the BIOS for this and try to enable it.

Otherwise, if your CPU doesn't support this, there is nothing you can do to run `intelhaxm.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Either you CPU doesn't provide Inter-VT technology or it has it disabled in the BIOS (every Lenovo Thinkpad computer with a i5 I've seen, for example, Intel-VT disabled by default in the BIOS).

Please, provide your CPU model so I can give you a more specific answer

Comment: it doesnot support the VT technology... i have checked if it is disabled in bios.. but after thorough search i came to the conclusion that my laptop doesnot support it!! i want a way in which i can make it support.....

Comment: No way. The cpu has to provide it. Otherwise, it is just imposible. Anyway, it would be better it you posted for cpu model here, so we can check it out for sure (sometimes they rename the BIOS setting and it can take a bit to find it)